# Number of solutions of equation of the form $a (x^{2}) + b (y^{2}) = n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I wanted to find the number of solutions to the equation of the form $a (x^2) + b (y^2) = n$. I was trying to implement [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) but I have no idea how to find the number of solutions to such equations efficiently. Efficient solutions are needed because otherwise I won't be able to generate list of prime number more efficiently then the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: What are $a,b,x,y \text { and } n$ ? Are you looking for solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: a,b,n will be constants. x and y will be variables. All real numbers

Answer (score 1):

There are formulas, based on factoring $n$ first, for the very special case when $a x^2 + b y^2$ is in a genus of only one class. Other than that, there is no general formula.

I am looking at *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* by Leonard Eugene Dickson (1929), pages 80-81. For example, the number of representations of $2^k m,$ where $m$ is odd and positive, is 4 times this difference: the number of divisors of $m$ that are congruent to $1 \pmod 4,$ minus the number of divisors of $m$ that are congruent to $3 \pmod 4.$

Since the power of 2 does not matter, I suggest you do this task for odd $m$ up to 99, count all solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = m$ allowing $x,y$ positive, negative, or zero without restriction, and also count up the divisors of each such $m,$ doing the indicated subtraction.

The jpeg below is also from Dickson. These are the "reduced" forms
$$  f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + c y^2,  $$
abbreviated $$ a,b,c  $$
with only one class per genus, up to a fairly large discriminant. The discriminant is
$$ \Delta = b^2 - 4 a c.  $$
For the table, Dickson lists $-\Delta$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate? Regarding genus of only one class.

Comment: @Zel, I'm going to make a jpeg of page 85 from Dickson's book. That should give you a beginning. Still, the real answer for your purpose is that there is no formula you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the problem over natural numbers. The number of solutions can't be determined for $ax^2+by^2=n$,

Consider $x^2+y^2=11$, no parity of $x,y$ will give you $3 \pmod 4$ . Therefore, no solutions.

Now we have $x^2+y^2=50$ for the same $a$ and $b$ you have $(x,y)=(5,5)(7,1)$.

You can surely eliminate the cases with no solutions by considering different $\pmod  q$.